# How to put more than one side braces for a vector

Tags: braces, vector

This code gives a single side brace for the vector (shown in black in image below).How can I modify this code to get two side braces (as shown in pink picture below) instead of single

[image]

```
    $${\bf x} = \left.\left( 
                                  \begin{array}{c}
                                         x_1\\
                                         \vdots\\
                                         x_{n_1}\\
                                         x_{n_1+1}\\
                                         \vdots\\
                                         x_n
                                  \end{array}
                            \right)
                        \right\}n
$$
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be easier ways, but here it is with stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
{\bf x} = \left( 
                                  \begin{array}{c}
                                         x_1\\
                                         \vdots\\
                                         x_{n_1}\\
                                         x_{n_1+1}\\
                                         \vdots\\
                                         x_n
                                  \end{array}
                            \right)
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\vcenter{\hbox{\stackunder[1pt]{%
  \left.{\Centerstack{\\ \\}}\right\}n_1%
}{
  \left.{\Centerstack{\\ \\}}\right\}n_2%
}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the braces need to be asymmetric:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
{\bf x} = \left( 
                                  \begin{array}{c}
                                         x_1\\[-6pt]
                                         \vdots\\[-6pt]
                                         x_{n_1}\\
                                         x_{n_1+1}\\[6pt]
                                         \vdots\\[6pt]
                                         x_n
                                  \end{array}
                            \right)
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\vcenter{\hbox{\stackunder[2pt]{%
  \left.{\Centerstack{\\}}\right\}n_1%
}{
  \left.{\Centerstack{\\ \\ \\}}\right\}n_2%
}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for Asymmetric braces. So good to have a general solution

Comment: If the labels have different length (e.g. n₁ and n − n₁), then the braces are no longer nicely aligned. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @RomanLangrehr One would need to issue `\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}` for left default stack alignment, either in the preamble (for all stacks) or prior to the `\stackunder` macro, if you want the effect to be local.

Answer (score 4):

You can create this using a number of well-placed `array`s and some `\vphantom`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\noleftdelimiter}{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \mathbf{x} = \noleftdelimiter
    \left( 
      \begin{array}{c}
        \begin{array}{c}
          x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_{n_1}
        \end{array} \\
        \begin{array}{c}
          x_{n_1+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_n
        \end{array}
      \end{array}
    \right)
  \right\}
  n
  ~ % Some space
  \begin{array}{c}
    \noleftdelimiter
    \vphantom{\begin{array}{c}
      x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_{n_1}
    \end{array}}
    \right\} n_1 \\
    \noleftdelimiter
    \vphantom{\begin{array}{c}
      x_{n_1+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_n
    \end{array}}
    \right\} n_2
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```